# How to eregi_replace to preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace

`eregi_replace('[0-9]+\.+[0-9]','',$cart['unit']);`

How to change it to `preg_replace`?

I get an error: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '+' in ---`

Comment: the thing is, I've tried but ain't work (how to fix this expression?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your existing Regex almost unchanged in a `preg_replace()`. Just add delimiters and a case-insensitive modifier. You get

```
preg_replace('#[0-9]+\.+[0-9]#i','',$cart['unit']);
```

In fact, the case-sensitivity is irrelevant since your pattern only matches `0-9` and `.`

Comment: Thank you/ you've helped. THANKS!